# How to upload deployment artifact in JFrog Artifactory with properties using JFrog-CLI?

Tags: jfrog-cli

I am able to

1. build the deployment artifact in Jenkins job **and**
2. upload this artifact with the below jfrog-cli command to Artifactory.

   jf rt u /home/appuser/temp/artifacts.zip project-artifacts-repo/ProjectName/GitBranchName/artifacts.zip --flat=true --server-id=app_artifactory

However, I am not able to update properties like 'GIT_COMMIT=$GIT_COMMIT;JENKINS_BUILD_URL=$BUILD_URL' in the same command for the artifact.zip being uploaded.
It throws the Wrong number of arguments (4) error.
Hopefully, jfrog-cli supports updating properties on the artifact zip file.

Can you please help me to update the above-mentioned properties in the same jfrog-cli command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using the `--target-props` command option.
To continue the example in the question:

```
jf rt u --flat=true --server-id=app_artifactory \
   --target-props="GIT_COMMIT=$GIT_COMMIT;JENKINS_BUILD_URL=$BUILD_URL" \
   /home/appuser/temp/artifacts.zip \
   project-artifacts-repo/ProjectName/GitBranchName/artifacts.zip
```

For more information, please refer to the [documentation](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/uploading-files).